# How to get value in NSDictionary from the textview of other viewcontroller in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a login screen where the user enters the email ID. When the user logs in and goes to other view controller, I need to pass the email ID to the `NSDictionary` object which I mentioned in another view controller.

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"abc@xyz.com", @"EmailID", @"http://www.yahoo.com", @"URL", @"344", @"Phone", @"", @"UserID", nil];
```

If I replace `@"abc@xyz.com"` to [`NSString stringWithFormat:@"@", firstViewControllerObject.emailIdTextField.text]` and try to get the output in log, I get a null value.

How to pass the email id entered by the user to `NSDictionary` object and get the value in log?

Using Xcode 4.6 and I am NOT using storyboards. Using `XIB` in my project.

Comment: How are you allocating/initiating firstViewControllerObject?

Comment: `stringWithFormat:@"@"`?  You mean `stringWithFormat:@"%@"`?  But have you thought about the fact that you aren't *formatting* anything and that statement is the same as simply specifying your argument; i.e.: replace @"abc@xyz.com" with `firstViewControllerObject.emailIdTextField.text`.

Comment: ***Before do anything*** do `NSLog(@"%@",firstViewControllerObject.emailIdTextField.text);` if its printing the value!

Comment: Ooops... I just saw the comments.

Comment: @Hemang i have use NSLog to get the value... still get (null) if i remove [nsstring stringwithformat..] and access the object directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two solution in my mind for you...

Say your two views are `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.

1. Simply just define a property in `SecondViewController` called `emailID` and when user logs in you are initiating `SecondViewController` at that time set the `emailID` property with the string value in the Email Id `textField`.
2. Also you can write your own `protocol` to achieve `Delegation` setup the email.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the format string. I think you forgot the "%" sign. Try the following:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", firstViewControllerObject.emailIdTextField.text]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

As I stated in my comments there is no point in using `[NSString stringWithFormat]` when the argument is `"%@"` as it does nothing, so simply do:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    firstViewControllerObject.emailIdTextField.text ... ];
```

Comment: This is right; stringWithFormat is superfluous. Check out my answer for a broader issue concerning object ownership.

Comment: still get (null) in nslog if i remove [nsstring stringwithformat] and access textfield as you suggested.

Comment: if i don't use [nsstring stringwithformat..], key value pairs are disarrayed and i don't get the key-value pair as expected

Answer (score 0):

For your other view controller (let's call it `otherViewController`) to access that field, `otherViewController` needs to 'own' the `firstViewControllerObject` object. I.e. the `firstViewControllerObject` object needs to be instantiated from within `otherViewController`. 
As far as the order of things in your app is concerned, your `otherViewController` should be instantiated first, and within it `firstViewControllerObject` should be instantiated and presented with `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `anotherViewController` logically need the email property, and the `firstViewController` own the `anotherViewController`.
So I think you may make `anotherViewController` a property named `email`, and let `fistViewController` pass the `email` to it while create the `viewController`.